# d3.request on(error) callback not triggering for 401 response

Tags: javascript, ajax, d3.js, callback, xmlhttprequest

d3: 4.8.0

I am forcing an HTTP 401 response in the backend to test authorization routines.

`d3.request().on('error', function(e){...})` is not being called.

d3 documentation which makes me think it should: https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#request_send

Sample JS:

```
var postData = whatever;

d3.request(someURL)
  .on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('In on(error): ', e);
  })
  .header("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  .send('POST', postData, function(error,response) {
      if (error) {
          console.log('Error in send() callback: ', error);
          return;
      }
      console.log('okay');
});
```

Console log expected:

```
POST https://someURL/ 401 (Unauthorized)
XHR finished loading: POST "https://someURL/"
In on(error): ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true ... }
```

Console log received:

```
POST https://someURL/ 401 (Unauthorized)
XHR finished loading: POST "https://someURL/"
In send(): ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true ... }
```

The on('error') callback is not being triggered.  I have tried changing the on() call place in the chain, which should not matter, and did not.

Answer (score 0):

In the question, send() with two parameters is preventing on() from triggering.  Here is an example which calls the on(error) in response to the 401 result, and the send callback from a success:

```
d3.request(someURL)
  .header("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  .send('POST', postData, function(response) {
      console.log('in send() callback with response ', response)
  })
  .on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('on() error: ', e);
  })
;
```